# Function scale_size_manual() isn't affecting the size of the points when using ggplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the function `scale_size_manual()` for the first time. I'm trying to decrease the size of the points using the script below:

```
p2<-ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Area, y = Proportion, group=linegroup)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(Collar)), size = 6, stroke = 0, 
             position = myjit)+
  geom_line(aes(group = linegroup),linetype = "dotted",size=1, position = myjit) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), width=0.3, size=1,
                position = myjit) + scale_shape_manual(values=c("41361´"=19,"41365´"=17)) + scale_size_manual(values=c(2,2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SNP" = "black", 
                                "LGCA" = "black")) + labs(shape="Collar ID") + ylim(0.05, 0.4)
```

However, the size of the points doesn't regardless of the number entered. I've seen other internet posts implementing this function in the same way, so I wondered if somebody could set me on the right track?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. My data:

```
> dput(dfnew)
structure(list(Proportion = c(0.181, 0.289, 0.099, 0.224), Lower = c(0.148, 
0.242, 0.096, 0.217), Upper = c(0.219, 0.341, 0.104, 0.232), 
    Area = c("LGCA", "SNP", "LGCA", "SNP"), Collar = c("41361´", 
    "41361´", "41365´", "41365´"), ymin = c(0.033, 0.047, 0.003, 
    0.00700000000000001), ymax = c(0.4, 0.63, 0.203, 0.456), 
    linegroup = c("LGCA 41361´", "SNP 41361´", "LGCA 41365´", 
    "SNP 41365´")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: You are controlling the point size in the `geom_point` call with `size = 6`. `scale_size_manual` takes a value mapped to the size aesthetic inside an `aes()` call and lets you control what size values are produced.

Comment: @JonSpring I tried the same script with ```ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Time, y = Proportion, group=linegroup, scale_size_manual(values=c(1,1))))``` as the first command line instead. The size of the point remains unchanged. Is that what you were trying to convey?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the size of your points in the `geom_point` layer by using the argument `size`.

```
geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(Collar)), size = 6, stroke = 0, 
           position = myjit)+
```

The only way to decrease the size of the points in your case is by decreasing `size`, e.g. to 4.

```
geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(Collar)), size = 4, stroke = 0, 
           position = myjit)+
```

You can only use `scale_size_manual` if the size is mapped within `aes` using a variable within data, like in the example below.

```
ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Area, y = Proportion, group = linegroup, size = Area))
```